# Domain Not Resolving to Forwarded IP

Tags: domain, ip, domain-name, godaddy, domain-registration

I've recently registered a domain name with GoDaddy.com and forwarded it to my web server's IP address.  Now when I enter the domain name in my browser, my site appears as expected.

The strange part is, when I ping the domain name, another IP address appears.  Is this normal?  I would expect it to resolve to my web server's address.  Is there anyway to make it resolve that way?

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted down my question.  If it doesn't seem clear enough, I'd be happy to clarify it.  It seems rude to vote it down without an explanation.

Comment: Probably the down voter misunderstood the question. Godaddy *can* forward the web access to another domain/IP.

Comment: @poige Please review the FAQ, **there is no such thing as a simple question**. Since SF and SE uses Google as the home page, and there is honestly no such thing as a **lame** question. There are badly phrased questions, but those are handled by 3K users and above.

Comment: @Diago Your opinion is clear; mine is as well, I hope.

Comment: @poige Not at all. I think yours was rude and uncalled for. There is a simple rule on SE, be nice. The question was valid, the user had a problem, he wanted and answer on a question 100% in the scope of ServerFault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you require the registrar (godaddy) to *forward* your domain, godaddy will redirect the web access from a domain to your IP.

```
Client ===> Godaddy ===> You
```

Godaddy acts as an intermediate between the client and you.

If you want to bypass godaddy, the client has to initially resolve your domain as your IP. So the change must occur at the DNS level.

If godaddy takes care of resolving your domain (and subdomains), as it is likely to be, you have to edit your DNS settings with the Godaddy interface.
Edit the `A` field for `@` (your domain name) and for `www` for instance (www.domain.name) that have to point to your IP address.

See [Adding or Edit A records](http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#arecs) in the Godaddy help.

Comment: how is this technical? It's not godaddyfault.com.

Comment: @poige The difference between a HTTP redirect and DNS resolution is not technical? What is your problem: almost half of your votes are negative - don't you think you could encourage well made answers, rather than down voting the ones you don't understand?

Comment: "See Adding or Edit A records in the Godaddy help." is not the difference.